# How to unselect previous state of Radio Button(UIButton)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, radio-button

I have a Scrollview in ScrollViewController and I have created Radio-buttons in another ViewController(RadioViewController).
Here is my code for creating Radio-button in RadioViewController:

```
- (void)setupBtn{

    self.radioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.radioBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(40,38,18,18)];
    [self.radioBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.radioBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"]forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.radioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.radioBtn];
    } 
- (void)radioButtonTapped:(UIButton*)sender{
    NSLog(self.radioBtn.isSelected? @"Yes" : @"No");

    if (self.radioBtn.isSelected) {
        [self.radioBtn setSelected:NO];
        self.view1.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        [self.radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }else {
        [self.radioBtn setSelected:YES];
        self.view1.backgroundColor = [UACFCustomColors continentalLightBlueTransparent];
        [self.radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    }


}
```

I always get self.radioBtn.isSelected = NO;

When I select one radio-button , if there are any other radio-buttons selected , how do I set those radio-buttons state to NO?

Comment: Total how many radio buttons you have?

Comment: @VinuJacob I have created 1 radio button add adding it to uiscrollview

Comment: Actually, you want to change the state of another radio button when you click the radio button.Right?

Comment: @VinuJacob yes...I mean I have to unselect the previously selected radio-button , if I select another radio button

Comment: For this, write the code to change the other radio buttons images inside the button click of the selected radio button.

Comment: @VinuJacob how to write it?since there's only one radio button

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following code.

```
BOOL radioButtonClicked;

-(void)setupBtn{
self.radioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.radioBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(40,38,18,18)];
[self.radioBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.radioBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"]forState: UIControlStateSelected];
[self.radioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:self.radioBtn];
radioButtonClicked = YES; // Add a boolean flag and set to YES
} 

-(void)radioButtonTapped:(UIButton*)sender{
NSLog(self.radioBtn.isSelected? @"Yes" : @"No");

if (radioButtonClicked) {
   radioButtonClicked = NO;
   self.view1.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
   [self.radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
   }
else {
    radioButtonClicked = YES;
    self.view1.backgroundColor = [UACFCustomColors continentalLightBlueTransparent];
    [self.radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-button-select"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

   }
}
```